# Find the lowest value of c.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

a, b, and c are positive integers.

Given

$\frac{1}{2015} = \frac{a}{5} + \frac{b}{13} - \frac{c}{31}$

Find the lowest value of c.

Comment: and what has been tried ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying by $2015$,

$$403a+155b-65c=1$$

We need to choose $a$ and $b$ so that $403a+155b\equiv 1\pmod{65}$, which reduces to:

$$13a+25b\equiv 1\pmod{65}$$

This congruence implies that $13a\equiv 1\pmod5$ and $25b\equiv 1\pmod{13}$. So, $a=2+5j$ and $b=12+13k$ for non-negative $j$ and $k$. Taking $a=2$ and $b=12$, we get:

$$806+1860-65c=1$$

or: $c=41$